# Steps to create Customized block in content editor in marketing cloud

Tags: visualforce, marketing-cloud, customization

I have a requirement to create Custom SDK Block.

Wondering if anyone of you has done it before if so how to do it.

Also it would be great if you share any reference document for this. (edited)

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a couple of Custom Blocks. It's pretty straightforward and the methods are very easy to use. The best starting point (aside from reading the [SDK documentation](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk)) would be to install a working demo app so you can see it in action and review the code. Here are a couple of public repositories that you should clone:

1. [Sample Block without SSO](https://github.com/tbesluau/sampleblock)
2. [Sample Block with SSO](https://github.com/tbesluau/sampleblockwithauth) (i.e. retrieve JWT to enable you to use SFMC API)

Note that the second app requires additional configuration of your installed package (which is not explained in the repo readme). I would encourage you to watch a video that walks you through installing this app [this video](https://www.salesforce.com/video/3621716) (fast forward to 11 mins in).

Comment: Thank you Harper. Could you please provide me video that how we can implement the custom block in content builder and drag and drop in email template step by step.It would be great for me to understand in depth.

Comment: Hey Harper, I have followed the same step and created the custom block in content editor it is drag and drop to email template but it is not showing me map and other function related details. Could you please let me know the exact problem here i am facing.

Comment: Did you implement the sample block without SSO (Google Maps App) or the one with SSO (Content Selector App)? I've tested both and they work. If you installed the one without SSO, you can review the video at https://vimeo.com/265518897. The other video link I provided explains how to configure the SSO version of the app.

Comment: Thank you! Harper it help me alot video and comment. I am using 2nd option and  marketing cloud app link i am using while adding component is incorrect, So it is not working. Could you please provide me short information about SSO and if possible can you provide me a more custom block sdk example. It might help to get more depth into it.

Comment: If you follow the video carefully, you should be able to reproduce this environment. Pay close attention to the configuration of the Installed Package and setting your Heroku environment vars. If you still have issues, you can [schedule a call](https://eliot.com.au) and I can assist further.

Comment: @ https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper ! Thank you for your help. I have followed the steps from video but facing some issue whenever i am dragging that in Custom SDK Block into email template, I am not able to edit. Please let me know your prefer time it will be helpful if we can schedule to look into this. Thank you in Advance.